# need to vectorize a function on a string

Tags: r

I have a 300K row dataframe with a column like this:

```
   db$performance[1:10]
   [1] "1C1CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC" "CCCCCCCCCCCCC"             
    "4321CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC" "321CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
    [5] "CCCCCCCCCCCCCC"            "4321CCCCCCCCCCCCC0"  "211CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC" "BCCCCCCCCC"     [9] "BCCCCCCCCC"                "8"
```

I want to search each row of that column and count the number of "4"'s that occur within the last (right to left) 18 character elements.  the loop solution i have is clearly bad, as it's very slow (6 minutes or more). see below.  How can i vectorize the solution (using apply, and/or dplyr?)

thank you!

```
substrRight <- function(x, n){
 substr(x, nchar(x)-n, nchar(x))
}

db$NewVar = NA

for (N in 1:nrow(db)){
db$NewVar[N] = str_count( substrRight(db$performance[N],18), "4")
}
```

Comment: You can just do `str_count(db$performance(v1, 18), "4")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_count` and `substr` are already vectorized.  So, directly apply the function on the entire column

```
library(stringr)
str_count(substrRight(db$performance, 18), "4") 
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

It should be fast enough.  Checking the timings on a bigger dataset

#### Benchmarks

```
db1 <- db[rep(seq_len(nrow(db)), 1e5),, drop = FALSE]

system.time({
out <- numeric(nrow(db1))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(db1))){
 out[i]= str_count( substrRight(db1$performance[i],18), "4")
}
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 14.699   0.104  14.755 
system.time({
sapply(db1$performance, function(x) str_count( substrRight(x,18), "4") )

})
# user  system elapsed 
# 14.267   0.075  14.299 
system.time({
str_count(substrRight(db1$performance, 18), "4") 

})
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.437   0.016   0.452
```

#### data

```
db <- structure(list(performance = c("1C1CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", "CCCCCCCCCCCCC", 
"4321CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", "321CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCC", 
"4321CCCCCCCCCCCCC0", "211CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", "BCCCCCCCCC", 
"BCCCCCCCCC", "8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: makes sense.  thx u.  here's a solution i wrote  just now as well. tmp = sapply(db$performance, function(x) {
 str_count( substrRight(x,18), "4")
})

Comment: @ElChapo  I think there is a misconception that `sapply/lapply` based solutions are better than `for` loop in terms of speed.  I would say that it is not.  For me, if I use `lapply` insstead of `for` loop, it is just to get the output clean without having to intialize an output vector to store the output in each loop